# How do video editors do audio downmix?

Tags: audio, mixing, production-audio, production-mixing

What mathematical formula do video editors use when they create a final mix of audio tracks?

Suppose I have a mono track `pcm_f32le` and 2 stereo tracks `pcm_f64le`. How do they calculate the loudness of each track in the output file? I'd like to do the same in `numpy`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simply multiply each sample with a factor and then sum it to get the output sample. In the example, if you want to create a new mono signal out:

out(t) = f1 x mono(t) + f2 x left(t) + f3 x right(t)

Where f1, f2 and f3 are the amplification factors, out(t) is output sample at time t.

The factors would typically be less than 1, so the calculations are probably best done using floating point numbers. If necessary there would be a last stage where out(t) is converted from float to whatever format you use on output.